# Searching for all functions with a certain property

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function with the following property: For all $x_1,x_2\in A$ if we take the line segment connecting the points $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$, take its perpendicular bisector, and see where it intersects the graph of the function, in that point the function has a slope equal to the slope of the line segment.

The linear function and the circle are obvious solutions to this problem, I'm searching for other solutions, if there are any.

Edit: I've found out this has some connection to the mean value theorem, I don't know if that's helpful or not. Also I think the function can't have an inflection point, although I can't prove it.